# words in a list - words in another list

Tags: python, list

Im new to coding and am looking for some help.

I need to remove words of a small list from a large list.

```
clean_book = [word for word in bwords_split if word in words_list]
```

I used the line above where `bwords_split` is the larger list and `words_list` is the smaller list and `clean_book` is the result. I think I'm thinking to arthemetically. Could someone help me?

Comment: If you need to remove the words in `words_list` from `bwords_split`, then you're doing it backwards. You'll end up with nothing _but_ those words. Just negate your condition in your list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution looks fine.  Just change the second "in" to "not in"